# Is “mortise & tenon joints” a good way to describe these parts?

Tags: phrase-request, image-identification

I have a pair of corner connection parts(shown as pictures below)
[image: part diagram]

[image: part diagram with a different view]

As you can see, there is one with a protruded head and the other one with a receiving cavity. 
What is the best and correct way to name them?

male / female connection part

or

mortise & tenon joints

Comment: Sorry, very confusing question. What parts *specifically*? What's with all the numbers? Please edit your picture, remove irrelevant stuff, add an arrow pointing to the parts you mean.

Comment: And explain the context of these diagrams! You might be best asking on a SE more specifically related to the subject you're asking about

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't call it a mortise and tenon joint, that is a woodworking term where one piece of wood is fitted into another. This looks like some kind of clip. Mortise and tenon joints don't clip together. If I needed to describe the connectors I would use "the male/female part" to describe it.

> Apply a thin coat of glue to the male part of the clip...